# Creating Last Modified SQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, syntax

I am trying to create a trigger to update `last_modified` field when the row is updated.

This is what i have tried:

```
USE `mydb`;

DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mydb.products_AUPD$$

USE `mydb`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `products_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON products 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.`last_modified` = NOW();
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is MySQL workbench wont let me save it (I'm assuming that there is something wrong with it but i can't find out what)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the version of MySQL Workbench I was using(6.0xxx) had a bug in it which played havoc with triggers. I updated to 6.2xxx.

**That was the first problem.**

**The second problem was** that i was using the `NEW` keyword in an `AFTER` trigger which is not allowed:

> Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table
>   (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and
>   NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is
>   updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to
>   be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

So my new trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydb`.`products_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `products` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`last_modified` = NOW();
END;
```

**Notice there is no `USE` or `DELIMITER` statement? That is because the new version of MySQL Workbench puts this in for you (including the end delimiter `$$`):**

```
USE `mydb`;

DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb`$$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `mydb`.`products_BEFORE_INSERT` $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydb`.`products_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `products` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`last_modified` = NOW();
END;$$
```